# Using SED to delete all XML elements which have certain values

Tags: xml, sed

We use a tool (pentaho data integration) which uses XML as layout for its files. It stores too much information in those files (like connection info). Before pushing the files to Git, I want to clear all connection-blocks which use JNDI. If I use XSLT (which could be a possibility) the entities will be resolved. This will cause Git to see a lot of changes every time I make minor edits - obviously undesirable.

I have a XML file with the following lines:

```
<connections>
   <connection>
      <name>connection1</name>
      <server/>
      <type>POSTGRESQL</type>
      <access>JNDI</access>
      <database>connections&#x2f;test&#x2f;connection1</database>
      <port>-1</port>
      <username/>
      <password>Encrypted </password>
   </connection>
   <connection>
      <name>test</name>
      <server>asdf</server>
      <type>ORACLE</type>
      <access>Native</access>
      <database>asdf</database>
      <port>1521</port>
      <username>asdf</username>
      <password>zcv</password>
   </connection>
</connections>
```

I want to reduce it to:

```
<connections>
   <connection>
      <name>test</name>
      <server>asdf</server>
      <type>ORACLE</type>
      <access>Native</access>
      <database>asdf</database>
      <port>1521</port>
      <username>asdf</username>
      <password>zcv</password>
   </connection>
</connections>
```

I can't use a XSLT parser (such xmlstarlet) because it will parse the entity reference (`&#x2f;` becomes `/`).

I've tried it with sed:

```sh
sed -ne '/<connection>/+.*/<access>/JNDI<\/access>/[\s\S]+.*<\/connection>/d'
```

but no luck there.

Comment: You don't want to use sed to process XML.

Comment: Why is resolving entities a problem?  If it's XML, then the two representations are equivalent.  If it's not XML, the question is mistagged (and you have bigger problems).  Either way, sed is probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: We use a tool (pentaho data integration) which uses XML as layout for it's files. It stores too much information in those files (like connection as explained in the example). Before pushing the files to GIT, i want to clear all connection-blocks which use JNDI. If i use XSLT (which could be a possibilty) the entities will be resolved. This will cause GIT to see a lot of changes every time you want to upload minor changes. Needless to say that this is something we rather not want.

Comment: thanks! good idea and done.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<connection>/!b;:a;N;/<\/connection>/!ba;/<access>JNDI<\/access>/d' file
```

This filters out connections which have access `JNDI`. However it will only do so if the XML is presented as is.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I've tried this and get the following message:    

    `sed: 1: "/<connection>/!b;:a;N;/ ...": undefined label ';:a;N;/<\/connection>/!ba;/<access>JNDI<\/access>/d'`

Comment: @RobSmienk  I suggest surrounding the commands by single quotes and or seperating each command using the `-e` switch i.e. `sed -e '/<connection>/!b' -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '/<\/connection>/!ba' -e '/<access>JNDI<\/access>/d' file`

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is not equipped for processing XML. If you want to do it right, use an XML-aware tool.

`xsltproc` would be such a tool. Use it with an XSL transformation like this:

```
<!-- dropJNDI.xsl -->    
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- output every node unchanged -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- except connection nodes with access = JNDI, do not output them --> 
    <xsl:template match="connection[access = 'JNDI']" />
</xsl:transform>
```

usage

```
xsltproc dropJNDI.xsl input.xml > output.txt
```

Comment: We use a tool (pentaho data integration) which uses XML as layout for it's files. It stores too much information in those files (like connection as explained in the example). Before pushing the files to GIT, i want to clear all connection-blocks which use JNDI. If i use XSLT (which could be a possibilty) the entities will be resolved. This will cause GIT to see a lot of changes every time you want to upload minor changes. Needless to say that this is something we rather not want.

Comment: Hm. if you always pass it through XSLT as a regular part of your build process, then all entities will be decoded consistently. Doing it with regex is asking for trouble and I would strongly dis-recommend it.